# How do I detach View windows in Eclipse Mars on openSuSE?

Tags: linux, eclipse, opensuse, kde-plasma, eclipse-mars

First, the basic operation is described in the Eclipse Help [here](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-9l.htm?cp=0_3_3_3)!

Unfortunately, it does not work as described there!

Does anybody get it to work?

Please keep in mind that it may behave differently on different platforms; I am running Eclipse Mars on openSuSE 13.1/KDE 4.11.5, and this may be of course the reason why it will not work at all ... :-(

It worked fine for all previous versions of Eclipse I installed on that machine before.

Answer (score 0):

Just drag them out of the workbench window (also works for editors in Eclipse 4...;-). Now you can also make a detached window contain more than one stack with its own maximize support...